# iOS Sprite Kit didBeginContact not work correctly

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have 2 images without background with triangles, I want connect one triangle with another, but Sprite kit thinking that my images is square not a triangle, and call me didBeginContact not in right time, for example:

[image: Imgur]

I create my sprite like this:

```
self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:spriteName];

[self.sprite setSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
self.sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.sprite.size];
self.sprite.physicsBody.mass = 0;
self.sprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;    
self.sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = Category;
self.sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
self.sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = Category;   
self.sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
```

Comment: You get boxes, you have to draw the polygon manually. There should be a line creation tool, if not, try cocos2d. Remember, your physics model and your view are different things. SpriteKit integrates them more than Cocos2d.

Comment: Thanks, but I think must be simpler solution.

Comment: The simplest shape is a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacts between two bodies depend upon their physicsBody, not their texture. So, when you use

```
self.sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.sprite.size];
```

You are attaching a rectangular physicsBody.

You need to create a triangular physicsBody using the method:

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
```

Read up on the method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithPolygonFromPath%3a).

In order to get the values for creating a path, you can use the [SKPhysicsBody Path Generator](http://dazchong.com/spritekit/) tool.

Comment: I try but have some problems, second node start didBiginContact maybe 200 pixels before he touching anything.

Comment: Do you use different textures for both triangles?

Comment: Firstly I try same triangles, first walking down and stay where I need, second move down and initiate didBiginContact before he touching first triangle, maybe 200 pixel far.

Comment: Try using a physics debugger tool, like one that can be found here: http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-physics-debugging-tool